# Spring Webflow - I would like to edit the http header varible in one servlet and redirect/forward to another servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I would like to edit the HTTP header variable in one servlet and redirect/forward to another servlet, in this second servlet I should be able to retrieve the header variable using `request.getHeader("MY_HEADER_INFO").`

The second servlet is actually running in a different context, hence I can't use dispatcher forward, hence I have used sendRedirect in the first servlet with code 302. I am using Spring Webflow.

SCENARIO:
When the user clicks on submit button he/she is being redirected to a URL in another domain with parameters to authenticate the user.
Once the authentication is successful the URL through which the second service received parameters is appended by custom headers post authentication and redirects back to it.
URL with headers gets redirected and hits my application then my `frontendcontroller` gets called in which I try to fetch the headers from the request. Unfortunately, I am not sure if I am missing something when try using `request.getHeader("Header_Name")`  i do not get the value and `NULL` is returned.

Whereas on second service side all the headers are being sent correctly.

What I have tried:

When I enumerated all the header names being received in the redirected URL I am not able to see custom Header added to request URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass request headers in a redirect. A redirect simply sends an HTTP response back to the browser with a `Location` header, which can only contain a URL in it. Hence, you can pass request *parameters* in a redirect, but not *headers*.

(I also don't think Spring or Web Flow are involved, just HTTP and Servlet behaviors.)